# How to set GIT_WORK_TREE with git-bash

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I have a static site inside the directory SITE, which I want to git-push to a github repo. I'm using windows and git-bash. I'm in the static1 directory:

$ls -la

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089   0 Oct 21 15:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089   0 Oct 20 18:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089   0 Oct 21 15:35 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089   0 Oct 21 15:36 .idea/
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 1049089 245 Nov  6 13:01 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 1049089   0 Nov  6 12:37 SITE/
```

I want to configure the GIT_WORK_TREE to point to SITE.

Following https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.7.8

I tried:

```
$ git config --local --work-tree="mypath\static1\SITE"
```

when I check:

```
$ vim .git/config
```

I see:

```
    [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

i.e. no changes . How can I set GIT_WORK_TREE at the repo level?

Comment: From [the entry in the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables), I'd guess the equivalent config parameter is called core.worktree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `core.worktree` but you must use an absolute path.

```
git config core.worktree /full/path/to/SITE
```

It might be easier to use `$PWD` to do this:

```
cd SITE
git config core.worktree $PWD
```

Note that if you screw this up, you may have to delete the `worktree` entry from `.git/config` manually.